# Increase method parameter value by 1 every time a specific method is called

Tags: javascript, class, methods

Two tasks that I am having issues with:

Task 1: Set the cat's initial age to a random number between 5 and 10

- How to prevent the random age from being overwritten

Task 2: Modify the class so that the cat’s age increases by 1 every five times it speaks.

```
class Cat {

  name;
  age;

  constructor(name) {
    !name ? this.setName("Norman") : this.setName(name);
    this.age = null;
  }

  getName() {
    return this.name
  }

  getAge() {
    return this.age
  }

  setName(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  setAge(age) {
    age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 5;
    this.age = age
  }

  speak(sound) {
    this.sound = sound
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "prevent the random age from being overwritten"?

Comment: @caTS Since I want the age to increment every 5 times the speak method is called, the initial age has to be set and unchanged, but the call to setAge causes the age to be over written by a new random age

Comment: But why do you always set it to a new random age and ignore the given age?

Comment: @caTS oops, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

(1) If you'd like the *initial* age to be random, place the random calc in the constructor. Make the age setter like the others, leaving the param alone...

```
constructor(name) {
  !name ? this.setName("Norman") : this.setName(name);
  this.age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5;  // note - 5 to 10
}

setAge(age) {
  this.age = age;
}
```

(2) the `speak` method can keep track of its calls with a little more instance data. Initialize it in the constructor, increment it on `speak()`, and test it there (for being a multiple of 5).

```
constructor(name) {
  !name ? this.setName("Norman") : this.setName(name);
  this.age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 5;
  this.spoken = 0;
}

speak(sound) {
  this.sound = sound;
  this.spoken++;
  if (this.spoken % 5 === 0) {
    this.age++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Or if we're really daring, `if (++this.spoken ...)` or even just `this.age += 1 / 5;` if the rules allow it :p

Comment: Thank you! Very straight forward explanation and solution